# Pymongo and Flask on Centos 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I want to ask for help. I want to use pymongo and flask, for an API on the virtual machine. I was able to install MongoDB, flask_pymongo and flask. I created a database in MongoDB and a collection named `LicencePlate`. And also wrote the following code.

```html
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'LicencePlate'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/db'

mongo = PyMongo(app)

@app.route('/framework', methods=['GET'])
def get_all_frameworks():
    framework = mongo.db.LicencePlate

    output = []

    for q in framework.find():
        output.append({'name' : q['nom'], 'language' : q['prenom']})

    return jsonify({'result' : output})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But when running this code nothing happens when I make a get request, error
`Error: Couldn't connect to server`

Comment: You should import PyMongo like `from pymongo import MongoClient` and and create the PyMongo instance like `mongo = MongoClient()`. Probably, this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_getstarted.asp) will help you to learn.

Comment: Also, make sure that the MongoDB process is running on your machine.